# How to make a Community Wiki answer

Tags: support

I see many references about Community Wiki and when it might or might not be approriate to make an answer with Community Wiki status.

I can't locate the mechanics of how to make that happen.

What are the steps to make your answer a Community Wiki answer?

Comment: There should be a tiny checkbox on the lower right corner of the answer pane for setting CW status.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, now I see it.

Comment: This answers half the question.  It also would be useful to know "when it might or might not be appropriate to make an answer with Community Wiki status."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J.M. pointed out there is a small checkbox on the lower right hand corner of the answer pane as seen in the figure below:

[image]